# No Success With Angular 2 Http Post to .Net Core Web Api 2

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

Been beating my head on this for a day. Just trying to make a simple POST to a .Net Core Web Api 2 service from Angular.

I'm using the Angular SPA template that can be downloaded for Visual Studio 2017 [I found from this tutorial](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2017-Launch/WEB-103)

Everything I'm reading online says the same thing, which I have done here as exactly as I can. No matter what I try, my Angular method isn't even hitting my Api method. I've been staring at this for so long, I'm pretty sure I'm missing something, but I can't see it.

Angular makes it very easy to do Http GETs, but I'm learning that POSTs are a pain in the ass to figure out.

Api Method

```
[HttpPost(Name = "AddSample")]
    public IActionResult AddSample([FromBody]Sample sample)
    {
        var result = _repository.AddSample(sample);
        if (sample.SampleId == 0)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

Api Sample Model

```
public class Sample
{
    public int SampleId { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
}
```

Angular Component Html

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h1>Add Sample</h1>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Barcode</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="barCode" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Created By</label>
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="createdBy">
                <option *ngFor="let user of users" value={{user.userId}}>
                    {{ user.firstName + " " + user.lastName }}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Status</label>
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="statusId">
                <option *ngFor="let status of statuses" value={{status.statusId}}>
                    {{ status.statusTxt }}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Submit" (click)="addSample(barCode, createdBy, statusId)"/>
</div>
```

Angular TypeScript File

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, Request, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { SampleModel } from '../../../models/SampleModel';

@Component({
    selector: 'addsample',
    templateUrl: './addsample.component.html'
})

export class AddSampleComponent {
private statuses: Status[];
private users: User[];
barCode: string;
createdBy: number;
statusId: number;

constructor(private _http: Http) {
    _http.get('/api/Status').subscribe(result => {
        this.statuses = result.json() as Status[];
    });
    _http.get('/api/User').subscribe(result => {
        this.users = result.json() as User[];
    });
}    

addSample() {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    );
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    this._http.post('/api/AddSample', JSON.stringify({ 'SampleId': null, 'Barcode': this.barCode, 'CreatedAt': null, 'CreatedBy': this.createdBy, 'StatusId': this.statusId }), options).subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result.statusText);
        console.log(result.url);
    });
}
}

interface Status {    
    statusId: number;
    statusTxt: string;
}

interface User {
    userId: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}
```

Comment: What is the response in your network tab?

Comment: Try changing your `HttpPost` attribute to something like this: `[HttpPost("[action]")]` above your API method. If your API method is never called, perhaps this is a routing issue. And, you should be getting some errors either in the console, or the IDE when running this.

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:51151/api/AddSample
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK

@R.Richards I'll try that now.

Comment: I figured it out, I wasn't including the controller name in the url..... O_o

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Just a tip ... "best practices" recommend *not* issuing Http calls from the constructor. Consider using the onInit lifecycle hook instead. You can see an example in the docs here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html